# Laravel Auth between subdomains Only Works With Remember Me

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 5.7, I have the following middleware:

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!\Auth::check())
    {
        return response("Not logged in!", 500);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

This works well when remember me is checked, but not when it was not checked AND the request is going to a different subdomain.  If I check remember me, it works well.  So the request goes from www.mysite.com to api.mysite.com.  The only time there are issues is again, when remember me is not checked.

For SESSION_DOMAIN I have .mysite.com and SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using api routes?

Comment: Yes, well using Dingo.

Comment: By default Api auth uses token driver, it could be the cause,

Comment: That wouldn't explain why it works when remember is checked?

Comment: Auth::check() won't work for api, you'll need to pass Bearer Token with your request as header and then verify it in your controller

Comment: Well, it does work, when remember me is checked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some time to figure out, but the main issue was that I was adding the bindings middleware into the route file:

```
$api->version(['v3'], [
'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\v3',
'middleware' => ['bindings'],
```

Once I removed the 'bindings' middleware, it recognized the session cookie instead of resetting it.  Only 15 hours to figure out that stupid mistake (on my part)..